# Highcharts - change values when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In script below I have two checkboxex - When is first one selected, I want to have only array "applesData" shown in graph. When second one selected, I want to "cherriesData" shown. When are both checkboxes selected I want to have sum of both fields shown (applesData, cherriesData). Any ideas? Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  var applesData   = [34, 32, 32, 35, 36, 39];
  var cherriesData = [54, 57, 58, 63, 67, 69];

  var categoriesName = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line',
      title: ''
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: categoriesName
    }
  });

  $('.parts').change(function() {
    value = this.getAttribute('value');
    while (chart.series.length > 0) {
      chart.series[0].remove(true);     
    }

    var outputData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    if (value == 'apples') {
      for(i=0;i<applesData.length;i++){
        outputData[i] = outputData[i] + applesData[i]; 
      }

    } else if (value == 'cherries') {
      for(i=0;i<applesData.length;i++){
        outputData[i] = outputData[i] + cherriesData[i]; 
      }
    }

    chart.addSeries({
      name: 'tons',
      data: outputData,
      showInLegend: true
    });
  });

  $('.parts').first().prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<label>
  apples
  <input class="parts" name="g" type="checkbox" value="apples" checked>
</label>
<label>
  apples urazem
  <input class="parts" name="f" type="checkbox" value="cherries" checked>
</label>

<div id="container" style="height: 250px; width: 600px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the `change` function gets called anytime that the checkbox value changes. Because you are resetting `outputData` on each call to `change`, it is impossible for it to ever sum apples and cherries, because you are using an `if else` conditional. So it either executes `0 + applesData[i]` or `0 + cherriesData[i]`, but never both. Because of this, you are only ever showing the apples count or the cherries count for each data point.

Take a look at the attached plunker, I've made a couple modifications to your code and separated some of the logic out into separate functions.

https://plnkr.co/edit/w4A0e8kjBOwN5v2tDpq5

Answer (score 0):

Is there some easy way how to add another checkboxes (+data arrays) to your solution? I need 11 checkboxes in total.